# Inset button between Send and draft button in outlook web addins

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to insert a new button like **Encrypt**  button between in Send button and Draft button as showing in the following screen.
[image]

I tried to change several ways in manifext.xml but not a success.

Answer (score 0):

Currently pinning an add-in to the top bar is not a part of the product.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on [our user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.